# i am trying to create a chart using PHP Google Sheets API error 400 Invalid requests[0].addChart: error pops up

Tags: php, charts, google-sheets-api

Hi i'm new to google sheets api. 
i was trying to create a chart using data within a google sheet. when i tried to add chat to the sheet using batchUpdate method error pops up.

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid requests[0].addChart: One of EmbeddedObjectPosition.overlayPosition  or EmbeddedObjectPosition.sheetId must be set",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid requests[0].addChart: One of EmbeddedObjectPosition.overlayPosition  or EmbeddedObjectPosition.sheetId must be set",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

im currently using PHP Google Sheet api V4 
this is the code snippet that causes the error.

```
        $chart  = new Google_Service_Sheets_EmbeddedChart();
        $chart->setSpec($chart_spec);
        $chart->setPosition(new Google_Service_Sheets_EmbeddedObjectPosition(
            array(
                'sheetId'=>$tab_id,
                'overlayPosition'=> new Google_Service_Sheets_OverlayPosition(array(
                    'offsetXPixels'=>20,
                    'offsetYPixels'=>20,
                )),
            )
        ));
        $created_chart = new Google_Service_Sheets_AddChartRequest($chart);

        $sheets_request = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
        $sheets_request->setAddChart($created_chart);

        $requests = [$sheets_request];

        $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
            'requests' => $requests
        ]);

        $response_batchUpdate = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileId,
            $batchUpdateRequest);
```

i read the google api documentation. wasn't much of help.

Comment: var_dump($tab_id = $result1->getReplies()[0]['modelData']['addSheet']["properties"]["sheetId"]);

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#embeddedobjectposition), and as also described in the error message you pasted above, both sheetId and overlayPosition cannot be set at the same time.

> Fields
>
> .
>
> Union field location. The location of the object. Exactly one
>   value must be set. location can be only one of the following:
>
> .
>
> sheetId number
>
> The sheet this is on. Set only if the embedded object is on its own
>   sheet. Must be non-negative.
>
> .
>
> overlayPosition object(OverlayPosition)
>
> The position at which the object is overlaid on top of a grid.
>
> .
>
> newSheet boolean
>
> If true, the embedded object will be put on a new sheet whose ID is
>   chosen for you. Used only when writing.

If you'd like to add the chart anchored at a specific cell on a grid, then you need to set the anchorPosition in [overlayPosition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#overlayposition)

> Fields
>
> .
>
> anchorCell object(GridCoordinate)
>
> The cell the object is anchored to.
>
> .
>
> offsetXPixels number
>
> The horizontal offset, in pixels, that the object is offset from the
>   anchor cell.
>
> .
>
> offsetYPixels number
>
> The vertical offset, in pixels, that the object is offset from the
>   anchor cell.
>
> .
>
> widthPixels number
>
> The width of the object, in pixels. Defaults to 600.
>
> .
>
> heightPixels number
>
> The height of the object, in pixels. Defaults to 371.

Otherwise, if you'd like to add the chart to its own sheet, you can either specify `sheetId` (if you'd like to specify the ID of the sheet to add the chart to, or `newSheet`, if you just want to add it to a new sheet with an arbitrary ID.

Comment: i want the chart to be in the same sheet as the source table.i have tried only with sheetId and without an overlay position but same error occurs.

Comment: Yes, as the answer above & the reference docs describe, use ONLY the overlayPosition field.  There's an anchorCell property in that field which includes a gridId, row and column index at which you want to anchor the chart overlay. The standalone sheetId field is only for adding to its own sheet.

Comment: thanks sam it worked perfectly. problem was that i was using SheetId field in Position field instead of overlayPosition->anchorCell->sheetId